# Does anyone know what is this LEGO Mursten set?

Tags: set-identification, vintage

[image: Photo of a vintage LEGO MURSTEN set box]

[image: Photo of the contents]

[image: Photo of the side of the box]

I'm having a hard time identifying what set this is. I want to sell it but I don't know how to name it.

Answer (score 7):

It's apparently [LEGO Mursten 700/6 Gift Package](https://brickipedia.fandom.com/wiki/700/6_Gift_Package), specifically the first variant from 1953-1954.

[image]

> Early versions of this set from 1953 through 1954 had only automatic binding bricks type windows and doors without glass. In 1954 they were replaced by tall classic windows and doors with glass. From 1956 to 1965, the set had only the classic type of windows and doors.

It appears it is listed as [700.6-1 Gift Package (Lego Mursten)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=700.6-1) on BrickLink, however the inventory appears to be of later versions of the set with newer windows.

Figuring out what it might be worth is likely going to be very difficult. There aren't may [similar sets listed or sold on BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=LEGO%20Mursten). What you have appears to be fairly rare, but it may be the kind of rare that nobody really knows about to look for and buy.